# Java 6 ECDHE Cipher Suite Support

Tags: java, ssl

The [Java Cryptography Architecture
Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites) page for Java 6 lists ECDHE cipher suites. Thus I would expect they are supported in Java 6. Yet neither OOTB Java 6 nor the addition of the JCE Unlimited Strength policy files is enabling them.

The book [Bulletproof SSL and TLS](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/bulletproof-ssl-and-tls/) also indicates Java 6 supports ECDHE, with a caveat:

> Enable and prioritize ECDHE suites on the server. Java 6 and 7
>   clients support these, and will happily use them. (But do note that
>   with Java 6 you must switch to using the v3 handshake in order to
>   utilize ECDHE suites at the client level.)

I'm assuming by v3 handshake he means SSLv3? I haven't tried it but even if this works, SSLv3 is not a viable option due to the POODLE vulnerability.

What am I missing?

Comment: how are you testing it? Any sample code? If connecting to server does it support ECDHE?

Comment: Yep the server definitely supports ECDHE. When I use Java 7 the initial client hello is passing a variety of ECDHE cipher suites and the server is returning TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA. No sample code ATM, I may provide in the future.

Comment: So what is the exception after server hello? Any alert?

Comment: I get the "Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)" exception but that's only because the server is returning me a DHE (non ECHDE) based cipher suite with a prime too large for Java 6. This is why I'm looking to enable ECDHE in Java 6, thus resulting in the server returning a corresponding cipher suite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SSL/TLS implementation "JSSE" in Java 1.6 and later supports ECDHE suites **IF there is an available (JCE) provider** for needed ECC primitives. **Java 1.6 OOTB does NOT** include such an ECC provider, but you can add one. **Java 7 and 8 do** include SunECC provider.

This seems to be a hot topic today. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74270/which-forward-secrecy-cipher-suites-are-supported-for-tls1-0-protocols
and https://superuser.com/questions/848698/testing-cipher-suite-using-openssl-for-tomcat-server-is-resulting-in-wrong-manne 
(which, suprisingly to me, was migrated from security).

Ristic's book undoubtedly means the v3 *format* ClientHello. There was a major format change between SSL2 and SSL3, and SSL2 ClientHello can't represent the data (particularly extensions) for ECC. All versions of TLS (to date) use the same *format* as SSL3, with (importantly) different *contents*. In the early oughties SSL clients often used SSL2 *format* ClientHello but with *content* allowing upgrade to SSL3 and even TLS1.0 in order to succeed against both/all servers, because many SSL2 were still in use.

Java 1.6 client circa 2006 was transitional -- by default it uses SSL2 *format* specifying *versions* up to TLS1.0, but if the server agrees to *version* SSL2 and not higher, the client aborts with an exception saying in effect "SSL2 is not secure". This is controlled by a pseudo-protocol string `SSLv2Hello`, so on Java 1.6 client you should `.setEnabledProtocols` to remove/exclude that.

Java 7 and 8 still implement `SSLv2Hello` but no longer enable it by default, so v3 format is used by default, or as long as you specify protocols to be (all) SSL3 or better. 7 and 8 also implement TLS1.1 and 1.2 which 6 did not, although only 8 enables them in client by default. You should only specify `SSLv2Hello` if you are connecting to way-old SSL2-only servers -- which of course you should try very hard not to do at all.

Answer (score 4):

The answer that dave_thompson_085 provided is correct and helped me, but I would like to add some clarification. As he states, the available algorithms depend on the JCE provider. I have Sun/Oracle Java 6 release 45 on Centos 5.4, which has no support for ECDHE OOTB.

So I need to add an additional JCE provider and Bouncy Castle (bouncycastle.org) is one. Follow the instructions here https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html#install
This extends the support to e.g. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

An alternative is to use the sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 provider bundled with the Hotspot JRE. You need a ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg
with the following content:

```
name = NSS
nssDbMode = noDb
attributes = compatibility
```

This will utilize libnss3, which may provide the necessary algorithms through the native OS library. This has been verified on Ubuntu 12.04, but may also work in other distros. It does not work on Centos 5.4, since RH/Centos 5 is [known](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65015/is-the-limited-elliptic-curve-support-in-rhel-centos-redhat-openssl-robust-enoug) to have limited Elliptic Curve support.

Comment: The proposed solution based on NSS didn't work for the cipher-suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, but the BouncyCastle solution did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on -Djavax.net.debug=all and see what's going on here, and provide sample code and logs.

In 1.6, SunJSSE supports TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider

So you should set your SSLContext with that as the enabled protocol.  Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLContext for details.  You also need to swap your enabled protocols so that 1.2 is enabled and in the lead.

Also see

- http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
- http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Security_Team/1/html/Defensive_Coding/sect-Defensive_Coding-TLS-Client-OpenJDK.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Chisther B. answer, this is the steps that I followed to get Java 1.6 working with ECDHE.

Download BouncyCastller (`bcprov-jdk15to18-169.jar`) copy it to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` and add the following configuration to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`:

```
security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Tested with Oracle JDK_1.6_211 against TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher suites.

My Dockerfile

```
COPY bcprov-jdk15to18-169.jar $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/
COPY java.security.bc.patch ./                                                                                                                                            
RUN patch $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security < java.security.bc.patch
```

java.security.bc.patch content

```
53a54
> security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```